# How to fix tezos-admin-client p2p stat returning error "CalendarLib.Date.Out_of_bounds"?

Tags: tezos-admin-client

Running Tezos alphanet branch (commit ea095e5992327716efa4a2d39bcb194df0df1f75)

Executing `./tezos-admin-client p2p stat` returns:

```
Error:
  Rpc request failed:
     - meth: GET
     - uri: http://localhost:8732/network/points
     - error: The server failed with an unexpected exception:
                CalendarLib.Date.Out_of_bounds
```

Other tezos-admin-client commands like `./tezos-admin-client rpc list` works fine.

Node log shows no errors and are chugging along fine, validating blocks as usual.

How can I fix the error and get the list of peers as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, see also [this issue](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/399).

A point can be greylisted too many times, so that the greylist expiration date (which increases exponentially) exceeds the max date bound for the date formatting library (somewhere around Y3K).

This can happen even for trusted points, because the greylist expiration is still increased for them as usual, even though they are trusted (it will just be ignored).

I don't know any good solution, except to figure out why a point got greylisted so many times, and make it stop happening...

As a temporary remedy, you can use `tezos-admin-client clear acls` to erase the greylists and blacklists.